# Attempt to delete row containing first responder that refused to resign

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield, first-responder

I have an iOS 6-based project that implements a `UITableView`. Each cell in the table view contains a `UITextField` allowing the user to enter information. If the user clears a text field, or deletes all input from the field, (i.e. `[textfield length] == 0`) when they tap onto another cell (text field) it deletes the previous cell (text field) from the table view, as it's empty - this avoids empty cells accumulating in the table view.

This is all done using a method called `-textFieldEditingDidEnd:` which fires on the `UIControlEventEditingDidEnd` event for the text fields:

```
- (void)textFieldEditingDidEnd:(UITextField *)textField {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = // Index path of the row in the table view

    if ([textField.text length] == 0) {
        // Delete the cell from the table view
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }

}
```

However, when the code is fired the app crashes with the following message on the console:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempt to delete row containing first responder that refused to resign'`

I have never seen this message before, and there do not seem to be particularly many references to it when searching the web. I would appreciate any suggestions on how to fix this issue.

Comment: try putting         [textField resignFirstResponder]; before deleting the row, see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but tried that before. No go, same problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've never seen that message before, but my immediate impulse if I were to see it would be: try delayed performance. Even something as simple as this might be an interesting experiment:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] 
     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
});
```

My thought here is, let's not try to delete the row while the text field is still reporting in (i.e. while `textFieldEditingDidEnd` is still running); let's give the runloop a chance to finish its cycle.

Comment: Cool-o-rama! And to think I was just guessing...! However, my idea didn't come completely out of nowhere; autolayout uses an extra runloop cycle, and so a lot of things about what you can get away with in the same runloop have changed in iOS 6. The underlying architecture has been fundamentally altered. So I'm finding this trick necessary in various circumstances.

Comment: @matt I know it has been a long time but you were missing a closing bracket on your last line (it should read  " } ) ; ")

Comment: This is a very bad answer. It is time sensitive and will not always work. Use textFieldEditingDidEnd and after that do the reloading. Otherwise it can still crash. Answer of @Rezier123 is more correct

Comment: @doozMen Actually, it's not "time-sensitive" and it _will_ always work. We are merely arranging to come back in on the main thread after the current runloop completes, and that is a completely determinate operation and precisely what we want to do. It's an important and valuable technique.

Answer (score 1):

i am also faced the same problem. while keyboard is present you need to call `resignFirstResponder` first then call `UITableview` reload method after

```
(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

delegate method executed  or inside:

```
(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    [tableview reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My crash was from an editable `UIWebView` inside of a `UICollectionViewCell`. The following fixed it:

`[self.view endEditing:YES]`

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the the same problem. Even though after calling "resignFirstResponer" and "endEditing" , It is found to be crashing.

When I tried with @matt's approach , it is working fine. Thanks matt.

It seems like since we are adding the "deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:" into the GCD queue , the queue will make sure that the previous task is completed in the queue and then only start the next task in the main_queue. Hence no need to add any delay.

Answer (score -1):

I came across the same `NSInternalInconsistencyException` exception. My solution was the following:

```
textView.selectedTextRange = nil;    // clear the selected text
[textView resignFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score -1):

Got this error when removing a `UITableViewCell` that contained a `UITextView` from a keyboard hide `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` notification.

Fix was to move the logic into `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification`

Answer (score -1):

I came across this issue when my method textFieldShouldEndEditing was returning NO in some situations