# TableView delete after I click button delete

Tags: iphone, ios

So I am trying to delete rows in table view.

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)done:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    DetailGodsViewController *detailController = [segue sourceViewController];  
    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:detailController.row inSection:detailController.section];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:path]
                     withRowAnimation:NO];
    [self.listOfGoods deleteGood: detailController.row];
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

I have ControlViewTable in storyBoard, after I click on a row in ControlViewTable it jumps to Detail view And there is other info, also I store info about the row and section in this function:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowGoodDetails"]) {
    DetailGodsViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

    detailViewController.row = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row;
    detailViewController.section = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].section;
    detailViewController.good = [self.listOfGoods getGoodAtIndex:detailViewController.row ];
}
```

and there is also a button in detail view for delete, after I click on it, it jumps to the function:

```
- (IBAction)done:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue.
```

But it always crashes in deleteRows. Could someone please help?

Comment: Could you add the reason of the crash and the exact line number or even better the full stack trace?

Comment: It crash when i try to delete the row -> [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:path]
                     withRowAnimation:NO];

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Answer (score 1):

One problem might be that you're still responding to the button while you're trying to get rid of the cell containing the button. You need to let that action method end, and *then* call deleteRows. You should probably do the sort of thing I recommend here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13907375/341994

However, the biggest problem is probably that you must update the model data before deleting a row of the table.

Comment: I dont understand where i can put the code you recommend me in http://stackoverflow.com/a/13907375/341994
and update model data how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Your code in the `done:` method is doing a few things out of order plus some extra things you don't need. It should be:

```
- (IBAction)done:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    DetailGodsViewController *detailController = [segue sourceViewController];  
    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:detailController.row inSection:detailController.section];
    [self.listOfGoods deleteGood: detailController.row];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:path]
                     withRowAnimation:NO];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Basically, you need to update your data before you update the table. Also, don't call `reloadData` on the table after calling `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:`. Do one or the other, not both.

Comment: Now it don't crash ,but it delete all data in table strange :(

Comment: 2013-02-21 21:55:31.793 AppGods[4362:c07] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <DetailGodsViewController: 0x75b9e90>.