# iOS image slicing with asset catalog creates strange artifacts

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, image

I'm stuck with this strange but hopefully simple issue and would love some help!

I have sliced an image within an asset catalog to look like this:

[image]

I then put this image as the background of a UIImageView within an xib:

[image]

This xib is called "tagElement" and is loaded as a subview of a UIScrollView view controller:

```
tagElement_View * tagElement = [[tagElement_View alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero Delegate:self Tag:tag andIndex:tagArray.count - 1];
[scrollView addSubview:tagElement];
```

Then, when the view finally loads it looks like this for a split second:

[image]

But, this is what the view settles down to after just a moment:

[image]

Does anyone know what would cause the image resize to occur only after a moment?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Alright, after a few more hours of debugging I was able to find a solution.  I needed to submit the UI updating code to the main thread in a completion block like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

    //  UI Updating Code

});
```

Although it's working, I'm not sure why I needed to call this..  I never started another thread to perform background work, and it seems like I'm just putting this task on the main thread.  But isn't this the thread that the task would have been executed on anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing by calling `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())` in this situation is asking to wait for one revolution of the run loop. This gets you past the commit of the current transaction, when all drawing, layout and animation take place. This in turn keeps your code from stepping on its own feet, as it were. It's a standard technique and is very useful in a system like iOS, where drawing doesn't take place until the transaction commits. In your case, it improves drawing; in many cases it can even prevent what would otherwise be a crash (as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13907375/341994).

Comment: See also my explanation here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_animation_transactions Look at the sidebar box at the end of that section, "The Truth About Transactions."